# Complexity of translation between Measurement Based and Circuit Based with Error Correction

Tags: error-correction, surface-code, transpile, compiling, measurement-based-qc

As I know,  translation between measurement-based and circuit-based is polynomial, not trivial, and might not be efficient in real time. It behaves this way because given some quantum circuit, we have to choose how to choose qubits in the cluster for the computation, an untrivial task.

BUT! Since we are dealing probably with a given circuit-based surface code set of operations, and a cluster in measurement-based has a similar structure to the surface, I wonder if the translation can be trivial and be done in linear time?

Comment: The translation is trivial: a patch of surface code corresponds to a cluster state defined on the Raussendorf lattice, see https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0610082. Any operation you wanted to do on the surface code just corresponds to simple modifications of the Raussendorf lattice, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.11780

Comment: Thank you @Jahan Claes, so I guess it means you do not agree with the answer provided by craig gidney

Answer (score 3):

Accourding to [Browne et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4673) it seems the translation from GBQC to MBQC is of size `O(N^3)` and from MBQC to GBQC the translation is of size `O(N^2)`; however, this indeed does not take into account the QEC pattern!

Comment: Please delete this answer and wrote it as a comment when you have enough reputation to write comments. "It seems" is not good enough for an answer on my opinion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Stabilizer simulation can be done in $O(gq + rq^2)$ time, where $g$ is the total number of operations, $q$ is the number of qubits, and $r$ is the number of measurements that needed random results. But that's just for the first sample. But you can generate *another* sample in $O(g)$ time by using the first sample as a template. Getting more samples is way, *way* cheaper.

The hard part of the stabilizer simulation is figuring out the relationships between measurements. Which measurements have to be 0, which measurements have to agree, etc. But if you already have a sample, those relationships are all implicit in the sample. You don't need to figure them out again. So the cost drops enormously.

In the context of converting between measurement-based and not-measurement-based computations, this means you don't necessarily need some high level understanding of the circuits. I don't know specifically what the exact information required is, but you probably don't need to be told "this is a surface code" and make some specialized surface code conversion methods. You probably just need something simpler and more universal like an example of a sample, or a hint about the location of the logical observable. Almost certainly any kind of real time system will require these hints to be included, so that any necessary conversions can be performed and verified efficiently.

Comment: Thank you, but I did not ask about simulation, but about compilation of hardware operation of ciruit <-> measurment based (for hardware purpose mainly)

Comment: @RonCohen It's the same basic problem. To simulate the system, you need to understand the relationship between the measurements. To convert measurement-based computation into something else, you need to understand the relationship between the measurements.

Comment: by efficiently, you mean that the conversion is trivial, and done in linear time?

Comment: @RonCohen Yes. And with small constant factors.